# Why is everybody downvoting my stuff?

Tags: discussion

I am just trying to help people but all my stuff gets downvoted. I am even being nice. They are making me loose all my priviliges and now I only have 9 reputation :(

Comment: Just a guess but you seem to be posting all Minecraft stuff. We've gotten **tons** of low quality Minecraft Q's & A's so ppl tend to be a lot stricter in terms of quality since we get so freaking much of it. Idk, I've hidden all the minecraft tags because of how bad it got.

Answer (score 5):

Looking at your downvoted questions and answers:

[How do you detect if somebody is on a certain y coordinate in Minecraft Bedrock?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/374255/how-do-you-detect-if-somebody-is-on-a-certain-y-coordinate-in-minecraft-bedrock) "do my research" question without any own research done. Let me clarify: we are definitely willing to ASSIST you towards a solution. What we won't do is GIVE you a ready made solution.

A secondary issue is that this is too broad of a question. You're effectively asking for 2 questions: How do I detect someone is a specific height (which by the way has an answer at [How to track player's height level?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/267591/how-to-track-players-height-level)); And How do I give someone I found a status effect (again, answered at [How do you apply potion effects to players?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/159991/how-do-you-apply-potion-effects-to-players)). Note that there actually is a full question for what you want to do at [Detect if the player is at a specific y level in 1.14](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/352682/detect-if-the-player-is-at-a-specific-y-level-in-1-14).

[Dark Oak trees are not growing indoors in minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/365530/dark-oak-trees-are-not-growing-indoors-in-minecraft/374259#374259): This answer feels low quality because your answer gives an appearance that you are unsure it's the correct answer. What would help is adding citations, like a link to the Minecraft Wiki.

[Is there a way to make the locator maps only show the player who is holding it?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/364100/is-there-a-way-to-make-the-locator-maps-only-show-the-player-who-is-holding-it/374252#374252): Again, feels low quality because you don't provide citations and sources.

Finally, an additional problem is that due to the massive popularity of Minecraft and the vast amount of customization that command blocks provide, we tend to get A LOT of low quality Minecraft questions and answers, to the point that most people are quite trigger happy with their downvotes on the topic. As a new user, your best bet is to not take these personally and just try your best to provide well researched answers.

Comment: Okay, thank you

Comment: The question you describe as "identical' isn't actually, because it is for Java edition and Anthony's question is for Bedrock Edition.